# Problem in understanding the coadjoint action of $\mathfrak {g}^{\ast}$ on $\mathfrak {g}$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, coadjoint-orbit

$\DeclareMathOperator\ad{ad}$Let $\mathfrak {g}$ be a Lie bialgebra. Then $\mathfrak {g}^{\ast}$ is also a Lie bialgebra which is dual to $\mathfrak {g}$. Let the brackets on $\mathfrak {g}$ and $\mathfrak {g}^{\ast}$ be denoted by $b$ and $b'$ respectively. Then how to define the coadjoint action of $\mathfrak {g}^{\ast}$ on $\mathfrak {g}$? I am familiar with the coadjoint action of $\mathfrak {g}$ on $\mathfrak {g}^{\ast}$ which is defined as follows:

Given $x \in \mathfrak {g}$ we define $\ad_{b}^{\ast} (x) = (\ad_{b} (-x))^{\ast}$. In terms of the pairing $(\cdot, \cdot)$ between $\mathfrak {g}$ and $\mathfrak {g}^{\ast}$ coadjoint action takes the following form:

$$\left (\ad_{b}^{\ast} (x) (\alpha), y \right ) = \left (\alpha, -\ad_{b} (x) (y) \right ) = - \alpha (b(x,y)).$$ Now how to define coadjoint action of $\mathfrak {g}^{\ast}$ on $\mathfrak {g}$? In one of the books on Poisson structures I have come across that it is being defined in terms of the pairing $(\cdot, \cdot)$ as follows: $$\left (b'(\xi, \eta), x \right ) = - \left (\eta, \ad_{b'}^{\ast} (\xi) (x) \right ).$$ Now $\ad_{b'} (\xi) \in \operatorname {End} (\mathfrak {g}^{\ast \ast})$. Then how can it act upon $x \in \mathfrak {g}$?

Any help in this regard would be warmly appreciated.

Comment: Are your algebras finite-dimensional?  Then $\mathfrak g \to \mathfrak g^{**}$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @LSpice$:$ I think it is implicitly assumed in the context.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439731/problem-in-understanding-the-coadjoint-action-of-mathfrak-g-ast-on-mat#comment1134178_439731), then your question is answered: an endomorphism of $\mathfrak g^{**}$ is transported to an endomorphism of $\mathfrak g$ *via* the isomorphism $\mathfrak g \to \mathfrak g^{**}$.

Comment: @LSpice$:$ There could be various isomorphisms between them. Right?

Comment: @LSpice$:$ What's the actual definition of such action? I mean why does it satisfy the pairing mentioned above? There should be some appropriate definition which satisfies the pairing.

Comment: @AnilBagchi. There is a canonical isomorphism between a finite-dimensional vector space and its double dual; yes, there are many isomorphisms between a space and its double dual (vector spaces have heaps of automorphisms), but there is one especially natural one, and it is that one you use to identify the two spaces in this context.

Comment: This is not completely explicit but $\xi\cdot g\in\mathfrak g$, for $\xi\in\mathfrak g^*$ and $g\in\mathfrak g$, is uniquely determined by the condition $\forall\eta\in\mathfrak g^*\ \eta(\xi\cdot g)=b'(\eta,\xi)(g)$.

Comment: Given that you understand the action of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $\mathfrak{g}^*$, this means that you understand the action of $\mathfrak{g}^*$ on $\mathfrak{g}^{**}$. This then suggests the following question. Suppose that $\mathfrak{g}$ isn't finite dimensional. Then the natural map $\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{g}^{**}$ is injective, but not surjective. Is $\mathfrak{g}$ then an invariant subspace under the action of $\mathfrak{g}^*$? Or do you know of an example where it is not invariant? Or is the problem that if $\mathfrak{g}$ is not finite dimensional then $\mathfrak{g}^*$ isn't a Lie bialgebra?

Answer (score 0):

As @Michael Barz pointed out in his comment above it turns out that $$\text {ad}_{b'}^{\ast} (\xi) = \varphi^{-1} \circ \left (\text {ad}_{b'} (-\xi) \right )^{\ast} \circ \varphi$$ where $\varphi : \mathfrak {g} \longrightarrow \mathfrak {g}^{\ast \ast}$ is the canonical isomorphism given by $\varphi (x) (f) = f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathfrak {g}$ and $f \in \mathfrak {g}^{\ast}.$ Now let us compute $\left (\eta, \text {ad}_{b'}^{\ast} (\xi) (x) \right ).$ We have $$\begin{align*} \left (\eta, \text {ad}_{b'}^{\ast} (\xi) (x) \right ) & = \eta \left (\text {ad}_{b'}^{\ast} (\xi) (x) \right ) \\ & = \eta  \left (\varphi^{-1}  \left (\varphi (x) \circ \text {ad}_{b'} (-\xi) \right ) \right )  \end{align*}$$

Now $\varphi (x) \circ \text {ad}_{b'} (-\xi) \in \mathfrak {g}^{\ast \ast}.$ Since $\varphi$ is an isomorphism (in particular, onto) there exists $y \in \mathfrak {g}$ such that $\varphi (y) = \varphi (x) \circ \text {ad}_{b'} (-\xi).$  So we have $$\begin{align*} \left (\eta, \text {ad}_{b'}^{\ast} (\xi) (x) \right ) & = \eta (y) \\ & = \varphi (y) (\eta) \\ & = \left (\varphi (x) \circ \text {ad}_{b'} (-\xi) \right ) (\eta) \\ & = \varphi (x) (b'(-\xi, \eta)) \\ & = - b'(\xi, \eta) (x) \\ & = - (b'(\xi, \eta),  x)   \end{align*}$$ as required.

Comment: @Michael Barz $:$ I think this is what you meant to say. Am I right?